# String.Contains not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, string, select-case

I have 54,000 files each with a slightly different method of naming and I need to check whether the filename contains a particular string. However, I can't find a ways of getting a Select statement to work correctly.

My code fails unexpectedly. Please can anyone tell me why the string "BAR" is not found in "BARITONE"?

---

```
Dim tempCheck as string = "1st BARITONE"
Dim GoodOne as Boolean = False
Select Case tempCheck
    Case tempCheck.Contains("CORN")
        GoodOne = True
    Case tempCheck.Contains("HORN")
        GoodOne = True
    Case tempCheck.Contains("BAR")
        GoodOne = True
    Case tempCheck.Contains("TROM")
        GoodOne = True
    Case tempCheck.Contains("EUP")
        GoodOne = True
    Case Else
        GoodOne = False
End Select
```

Comment: Please don't do it that way ! define a generic list of acceptable strings, then loop through it and as soon as you find a matching value, set a flag to true and get of the loop. That way you don't need to add lines of codes if values are added. It's even better if values aren't hardcoded but in some config file !

Comment: @Bartdude Even easier with Linq: `things.Any(i => stuff.Contains(i))` (C#, but still).

Comment: @GrantThomas : unfortunately I haven't been able to use Linq in any of my current projects, but each time I see one of these lines I'm even more eager to try it. Seems to definitely save a LOT of time !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
    Dim tempCheck as string = "1st BARITONE"
    Dim GoodOne as Boolean = False
    Select Case True
        Case tempCheck.Contains("CORN")
            GoodOne = True
        Case tempCheck.Contains("HORN")
            GoodOne = True
        Case tempCheck.Contains("BAR")
            GoodOne = True
        Case tempCheck.Contains("TROM")
            GoodOne = True
        Case tempCheck.Contains("EUP")
            GoodOne = True
        Case Else
            GoodOne = False
    End Select
```

[SELECT CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) doesn't work on strings like this (you have to compare string to a string, in this case you compare to a boolean). It does work on Booleans compared to booleans

Comment: What would be the advantage of this over a series of `If` statements?

Comment: @CodyGray none; but at least this one works. I personally don't see any special reason for use case statement ever.

Comment: @CodyGray not much, just keeping with OP original structure

Comment: +1 for giving a solution meeting the expectations of the OP perfectly (even the select case structure).

Comment: I don't believe it! Thanks Yuriy.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Select Case wrong.  Just use a simple if else:

```
Dim tempCheck As String = "1st BARITONE"
Dim GoodOne As Boolean = False
If tempCheck.Contains("CORN") Then
    GoodOne = True
ElseIf tempCheck.Contains("HORN") Then
    GoodOne = True
ElseIf tempCheck.Contains("BAR") Then
    GoodOne = True
ElseIf tempCheck.Contains("TROM") Then
    GoodOne = True
ElseIf tempCheck.Contains("EUP") Then
    GoodOne = True
End If
```

Comment: It would work in VB.NET (even if it's not best practise): `Select Case True
            Case tempCheck.Contains("CORN")`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I suppose (and the other answer demonstrates that), but honestly you are bending Select Case for something it's not really intended for at that point.  I'd prefer my answer.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in using If...ElseIf. But I just prefer Select Case - most of the time:)